# Getting UIImage from different directories in Resources folder

Tags: iphone, uiimage

I want to put my images into different directories in Resources folder. For example I have 1.jpg (large) and 1.jpg (thumbnail). So I want to locate them 2 different directories.

If I want to get them, I should use [UIImage named:@"large/1.jpg"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use should use a bundle for that

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AboutBundles/AboutBundles.html

Actually, using a bundle is also a nice way to separate and organize resources for an application with target for different devices.

To create a bundle for your resources you could do the following:

1. File -> add new file
2. Select the `Resources` menu
3. Select `Settings bundle`
4. Choose the file name and location

To start using that bundle only for images and other resources, you can delete all default files that are already there (which are specific for the settings bundle and your are not using this bundle for that)

An interesting point is that, while working with bundles, you will not manage your budle files through `XCode` anymore, you will have to add/remove them only in `Finder`.

Comment: Can I add the images that I downloaded from internet during runtime of the application programatically?

Comment: All file management done in runtime should happens inside the `Documents` or the `Library` folder. Your bundle (and also any file located in your `Resources` folder) will be placed inside your application package, which your app has read only access. given that, your folder name will be useless for runtime file management... You cold take a look at the TCImageView github project https://github.com/totocaster/TCImageView, as he uses the image content data to create a hash and them uses it as unique file names for all images, then you will solve the folders issue.